# Google Chrome is not playing Autoplay Media Audio (.mp3), while other browsers does play

Tags: html, html5-audio

MY WEBSITE:::   https://mslen.heliohost.org/CMASHOUSE.html

It's a basic page. Audio is not playing on chrome, but plays on IE

Secondly, as an alternate  would play when user clicks. I don't want the control to show on the page...wants the control to be hidden

PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED!

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code first? Nobody can fix or explain the code that he/she didn't see.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't allow Autoplay unless user interacts with website first, ie, clicks somewhere in the page. This is so a user doesn't open 5 tabs and has audio play from all 5 tabs in the background before they've clicked in to the tab. You can [read more about it here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

As for hiding the controls, modify your `<audio>` tag not to include `controls`.

Ie, where you have:

```
<audio controls autoplay loop="99">
```

Replace with;

```
<audio autoplay loop="99">
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) you can find more info about the `<audio>` tags.